# Help with app, (force close)

Tags: android

**I created an app, on eclips, but when i try to run it is force close why?
logcat :**

```
03-16 19:28:09.820: INFO/ActivityManager(439): Start proc com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI for activity com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI/.Jaribarh_soundbord: pid=2621 uid=10020 gids={1015}
03-16 19:28:09.860: DEBUG/AK8973(415): Compass Start
03-16 19:28:09.860: DEBUG/Sensors(439): open_akm, fd=126
03-16 19:28:09.870: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2621): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-16 19:28:09.910: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2621): Shutting down VM
03-16 19:28:09.910: WARN/dalvikvm(2621): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40025a18)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI/com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI.Jaribarh_soundbord}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI.Jaribarh_soundbord in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI-2.apk]
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2755)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2854)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:136)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2179)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI.Jaribarh_soundbord in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI-2.apk]
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1034)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
03-16 19:28:09.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2621):     ... 11 more
03-16 19:28:09.920: WARN/ActivityManager(439):   Force finishing activity com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI/.Jaribarh_soundbord
03-16 19:28:10.420: WARN/ActivityManager(439): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{48894070 com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI/.Jaribarh_soundbord}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class `com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI/.Jaribarh_soundbord` doesn't exist. Possibly a misspelling of *soundboard*?

Comment: nope, I try to put soundboard in sted of the soundbord, but it's stille force close, maybe you want to se the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the important line from your log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.soundboard.Jaribarh.LIL_SIDDI.Jaribarh_soundbord
```

Is there a typo in the class name, or is it possible that this Activity is not declared in the Manifest?

Comment: Can't find any thing, do you want to se the mainifest ?